# grafana plotting data distribution

Tags: grafana

I have data similar to this:
- (timestamp1, "A", "1", 21)
- (timestamp2, "A", "3", 16)
- (timestamp3, "A", "4=>8", 4)
- (timestamp4, "A", "9=>12", 3)

which can be represented as a distribution:

[distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uylf9.png)

Is it possible to plot such a distribution in grafana, while specifying timerange (i.e: timestamp1 to timestamp4)?

Answer (score 0):

There is the histogram plugin https://grafana.net/plugins/mtanda-histogram-panel. But this would not need your data already in distribution format but the original time series data. But I suppose you can only do equally spaced bins with this.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up by making a custom version of this grafana plugin, cheers